# Entity Framework 4 Delete Object from entity collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have a "Request" Entity with an 1..* relationship to the "RequestProperty" Entity. So there's a collection of RequestProperty objects in "Request". When I update a "Request" I want to delete all items in the RequestProperty EntityCollection and add the new items from the incoming domain object. When I iterate over the `Request.Properties` collection and call a remove or a `DeleteObject` on the item, the enumeration fails because the collection has been modified.

As of now I'm doing this:

```
while (true)
{
    if (newRequest.Properties.Count > 0)
        context.RequestPropertySet.DeleteObject(newRequest.Properties.First());
    else
        break;
}
```

Since this is not really "cool" I thought there must be another way to empty a collection of a relationship. Thank you for your thoughts.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer depends on the way you modeled your entities. If you are using common independent relation or foreign key relation you will have to use your current approach - I'm using it as well in my project.

If you defined identifying relation you will be able to call just `Clear` on collection as @Craig described. Identifying relation is special relation where primary key of dependent entity contains foreign key of parent entity.

[image: Example EF model]

The example shows `Order` entity and `OrderItem` entity with foreign key identifying relation between them. Primary key of `OrderItem` consists of unique `Id` and `OrderId` which is FK of `Order` table. With this configuration you don't need to iterate through `OrderItem`s and delete each item separately. Simply removing `OrderItem` from collection will be executed as delete in database and clearing collection will delete all related `OrderItem`s in database.

Comment: I'm trying to use essentially the same model structure as Order <-association-> OrderItem above, without success. I keep getting the following error at runtime:
Namespace.Models.OrderItem: : EntityType 'OrderItem' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
OrderItem: EntityType: EntitySet 'OrderItems' is based on type 'OrderItem' that has no keys defined.

The main difference is that I don't have any non-key properties in OrderItem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Clear()` method:

```
newRequest.Properties.Clear();
```

Comment: Won't work as the foreign key column on the RequestProperty table is not nullable. I guess I could change that and/or set a cascade on delete.

Comment: In this case you *should* set a cascade on delete, IMHO.