# How to use a foreign key as a part of a composite primary key in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, database-design, composite-key

I've got an entity which is identified by no own id but an unique combination of properties, each of which is a foreign key.

But Entity Framework designer does not seem to allow to make a foreign key (a "navigation property") a part of a primary key. Am I misunderstanding something or is it just unsupported?

Example:

[image]

here an instrument is designated by a very short symbolic identifier (name), which doesn't seem to be wise to be replaced by a numeric code.

Comment: is it .net 3.5 or 4.0? What did you get in the designer?

Comment: @ladislav-mrnka, .Net 4.0, VS 2010, there is just no "entity key" property available for "navigation properties".

Comment: I don't know about EF designer.  In traditional ER design with paper and pencil, entities don't have foreign keys as part of their PK.  Subentities and relationships do.  Is value a subentity of instrument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigation properties cannot be part of primary key. Composite primary key (entity key) can consists only from scalar properties -> only foreign properties related to these navigation properties can be part of FK - [here is the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922228/entity-framework-4-delete-object-from-entity-collection/4925040#4925040) of the model which uses such relation.