# MySQL + Entity Framework: Can't delete object

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, cascading-deletes

I'm trying to delete an object that has foreign key relationships via the Entity Framework (MySQL/Connector).

*ClientAccount* >>> ClientEmailAddresses

```
  foreach (ClientAccount client in recsClientStore.Deleted) {   
        ClientAccount stub = new ClientAccount();
        stub.Id = client.Id;
        this.DBContext.AttachTo("ClientAccounts", stub);


        stub.FkClientEmailAddresses.Clear();
        this.DBContext.DeleteObject(stub);
    }

    this.DBContext.SaveChanges();
```

.. but when I do this I get the following error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

I'm not really sure where this leaves me. Do I have to delete the EmailAddress object first? We're wary of turning on cascade but it's looking more and more like this is required to tidy up foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this:

```
stub.FkClientEmailAddresses.Clear();
```

doesn't delete relations. It only set FK in related entities to null. If you want them really delete you must either:

- Delete them by calling `Remove` on their object set
- Change relation to [identifying relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922228/entity-framework-4-delete-object-from-entity-collection/4925040#4925040) - that will make `Clear` work as expected
- Correctly setup cascade delete in both EDMX and database and do not call Clear at all

Comment: Thank you. I think we're going to have re-examine our structure to establish whether we really need cascading.