# EF code first: How to delete a row from an entity's Collection while following DDD?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, code-first

So here's the scenario:

DDD states that you use a repository to get the aggregate root, then use that to add/remove to any collections it has.

Adding is simple, you simple call `.Add(Item item)` on the `Collection` you wish to add to. A new row is added to the database when you save. However, deleting is different - calling `.Remove(Item item)` doesn't remove the item from the database, it simply removes the foreign key. So while, yes, it is technically no longer part of the collection anymore, it's still in the database.

Reading around, the only solution is to delete it using the data context. But according to DDD the domain object shouldn't be aware of the data context so therefore deleting will have to be done outside of the domain.

What is the right way to go about this? Or Is leaving the database full of orphans acceptable (perhaps running a routine to clear them out)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've solved this problem in the application I'm currently working on by using [domain events](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/); a DDD concept [Eric Evans said](http://gojko.net/2009/03/12/qcon-london-2009-eric-evans-what-ive-learned-about-ddd-since-the-book/) should have been in his book.

While domain objects aren't allowed to know about the object context, an `IDomainEventHandler` is - I've therefore got a `DomainObjectDeletionHandler` which deletes 'removed' objects from the object context before control returns to my application layer and the changes are saved.

For more information, I've written [a blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/mrsteve/archive/2011/07/21/self-configuring-domain-event-handlers.aspx) about my implementation of domain events and how I approached hooking everything together.

Hope that helps :)

**Edit**

For example, if you have an `Order` class which has an `OrderItems` collection of type `OrderItem`:

```
public class Order
{
    // Other stuff

    public void RemoveOrderItem(int orderItemId)
    {
        var orderItemToRemove = OrderItems.First(oi => oi.Id == orderItemId)

        OrderItems.Remove(orderItemToRemove);

        DomainEvents.Raise(new OrderItemRemoved(orderItemToRemove));
    }
}
```

Comment: When exactly would you Raise the deletion event?

Comment: From a method on the domain object doing the deleting - I've updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

When removing a child entity from a collection, EF will leave it as orphan, removing just the foreign key.

If you don't want to explicitly remove it using the DbContext, you can use what it is called "Identifying Relationship" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee373856.aspx at the bottom).

The trick is to set a composite primary key on the child including the parent's primary key.

Once you do that, when removing the entity from the parent's collection, it will be removed from the table as well.

Comment: This answer is understated. I too was initially concerned with EF's behavior on "orphaning" removed entities (or in case of foreign key constraints, its inability to proceed at all), but configuring the composite key as noted does indeed cause these entities to be physically deleted from the database when you remove them. I love some of the other suggestions such as using Domain Events, but seems a much simpler fix to just change the key.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if this is by design, but if a detail object has a composite key containing its master object's key columns, it will be automatically deleted if you remove it from the master object's collection. If you have an Order object with an OrderID key and ICollection OrderLines navigation property, give OrderLine a composite key containing OrderID and OrderLineID.

But since I do not know if I can rely on that, the solution I've used myself is to let EF handle it the way it does, and fix up 'detached' (not in EF terms) detail objects on the call to SaveChanges(), enumerating over all modified entities and changing the state to deleted as appropriate.

Comment: In terms of EF it is called [identifying relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922228/entity-framework-4-delete-object-from-entity-collection/4925040#4925040).

Answer (score 2):

I solved this scenario by configuring the reference column as required and the delete behavior as `Cascade`

Example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AggregateRoot>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Items)
    .WithOne()
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

In this case, EF Core (6.x) no longer set the reference column to `NULL`, but deleted the record just by removing the `Item` from the `Items` collection of the aggregate root.

The decisive configuration here was the delete behavior `Cascade`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use two repositories?

```
var parent = ParentRepo.Get(parentId);
parent.Children.Remove(childId); // remove it from the property Collection
ChildRepo.Delete(childId); // delete it from the database
ParentRepo.Commit(); // calls underlying context.SaveChanges()
```

Assuming you're sharing contexts via IOC/DI, calling commit with one repo will commit for both, otherwise just call `ChildRepo.Commit` as well.