# Detect Relationship changes EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am currently migrating from Entity Framework 6 to Entity Framework Core and have run into a problem.

I want to be able to detect if there are any relationship changes in my DbContext for all/specific entities. Previously I had leveraged a solution for EF6 as documented here in this SO question: [Entity Framework 6: detect relationship changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707344/entity-framework-6-detect-relationship-changes).
However that uses `ObectStateManager` and `GetObjectStateEntries` which as far as I can tell aren't available to use in EF Core.

Has anyone any experience in this or guidance on same?

Comment: The state tracker is still in there, just under a different name. This can easily be Googled.

Comment: @Flater You assume that I haven't googled. Is it the `ChangeTracker` object that you are referring to? Or is there a separate State Tracker object? If it is the ChangeTracker I cannot easily find how to detect Relationship changes. To clarify, it is not Add,Delete,Update that I want to detect but rather Changes in the relationships between entities, for example in a One-to-Many relationship if the Many side of the relationship changes?